# Determine Editorfor or TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox, editorfor

I'm new to MVC/C# and have the following code in a CSHTML file.  Basically it determines the operation being performed (insert or update) and based on the the result decide whether the field should be displayed read-only or editable.

```
@if (Model.DatabaseOperationFlag == DatabaseOperation.Update)
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BmUnit.BMU_ID, new {@readonly = "readonly"})
}
else
{
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BmUnit.BMU_ID)
}
```

The code is going to be needed throughout the app but I am unsure where/how I can write some sort of control so I can use code similar:

```
@Html.ReadOnlyOnUpdate(model => model.BmUnit.BMU_ID, model.DatabaseOperation);
```

The ReadOnlyOnUpdate would then do the logic in the first code section.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should use @Html.DisplayFor()  for read only view.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper that would do that for you. Create a class with a method that extends off of HtmlHelper:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static IHtmlString ReadOnlyOnUpdate(this HtmlHelper helper, int BMU_ID, DatabaseOperation operation)
    {
        var attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (operation == DatabaseOperation.Update)
        {
            attrs.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }
        return helper.TextBox("BMU_ID", BMU_ID, attrs);
    }
}
```

Through the use of generics, you could probably setup an extension method that you could do if off the model and the BMU_ID specifically. Create something similar to EditorFor:

```
public static IHtmlSTring ReadOnlyOnUpdateFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<TModel, TProperty>> expression, DatabaseOperation operation)
```

You would just have to replace TModel with your model type and TProperty with the type of BMU_ID I believe.

Hopefully this helps.